# Firing Events when SWF file ends playing?

Tags: flash

Here What I want is to play a swf file in my site. And when that **swf animation file ends** that is fully watched by the User, **I want to call a PHP page**.

Any type of help will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a SWF that contains some **ActionScript Events** and allow javascript interaction between flash and javascript by calling it with some parameters like ['allowScriptAccess'](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html).

This way the flash player will fire some events that you can register with javascript functions.

So either you have some control on the flash animation (source) and you add your own callbacks (check [adobe documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html)), or you are simply playing a video and you need a player that already provides some js events. In this second case you'll have to search a little, but here's for example the javascript interface of the [youtube player](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#EventHandlers) or the [JW Player one](http://www.kpbowler.co.uk/node/17).